# make animation wait for 1 sec – Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm working on a memory game with 6 UIButtons that changes background-image when they're touched. I check if two of the taped ones are the same with booleans. I have 6 different and each set to YES in each button action.

If first BOOL not is equal to second BOOL then they should change back to their original background-image. My problem is that when the second button is clicked, directly, the two buttons changes. I want the second button's image to be seen before they change. This is my code:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
buttonClickedBOOL = YES;

[animation stuff....]
if (randomNumberi == 0)
{
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if (randomNumberi == 1)
{
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"windows_logo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else if (randomNumberi == 2)
{
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fujitsu.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
[UIView commitAnimations];

[self gameCheck];
}
```

This is where I check the conditions:

```
- (void)gameCheck
{
if ((buttonClickedBOOL == YES) && (button2ClickedBOOL == YES))
{
    button.enabled = NO;
    button2.enabled = NO;
    button3.enabled = NO;
    button4.enabled = NO;
    button5.enabled = NO;
    button6.enabled = NO;

    if (randomNumberi == randomNumberi2)
    {
        NSLog(@"The same");
    }
    else
    {
        [animations stuff....]
        [button setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [animations stuff....]
        [button2 setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

}
```

The random variables are set in viewDidLoad to int numbers 0-3 and represents which images which should be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your animation code in a different method and call it like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourAnimatingMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Comment: to the animation that you want to delay by 1 second

Answer (score 1):

From the [`UIView` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

Use the method `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`

This method takes a delay parameter. It also uses blocks for the animation and completion handler. It is very useful.

Comment: can you please explain how to use this?

Comment: I'd recommend this, using `[UIView commitAnimations]` is deprecated and may no longer work in a later version of iOS

Comment: whenever I write a method that contains block parameters I depend heavily on Xcode's autocomplete for the block parameters. This way when it selects the parameter blurb (or whatever those things are called) you can just hit enter and the block will be formatted with the correct parameters. For an example, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3238650/1074558

Comment: Blocks are really useful, basically you are passing code to be run into a method, and the method calls that code when it needs to. It depends on the method for when it actually gets called, for our animation example, the animations block is what gets called for the animations (everything before commitAnimations). The completion block then gets called when the animation finishes.